# How to center the navigation bar in CSS

Tags: css, navigation

I have difficulties in centering my navigation-bar. Tried a lot of things like `background-position: center` or `display: inline-block; list-style-type: none;` It doesn't seem to work. Also I'm not able to simply put a margin on the left side. Do you have some other ideas to center the bar? http://www.filmfutter.com/forum/

```
.zetta-menu {
 background-color: #000;
 background-position: right center;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 0;
 max-width: 978x;
 min-height: 30px;
 position: relative;
```

Comment: Can we please see the HTML you're trying to center?  The HTML to center may affect how you center it.  Sometimes `text-align: center` will do it, other times you want `margin: 0 auto`.  It all depends on how you structure the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin:0 auto;`

...................

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the element is set to `display: block;` and center it with `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to centre with `margin:auto`.

Note: You have some other declarations elsewhere in your CSS that are setting the margin to 0 so I've added `!important` in this example.

```
.zetta-menu {
    background-color: #000;
    background-position: right center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 0;
    max-width: 978x;
    min-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto!important;/* < just add this line to what you have already */
}
```

Comment: That `!important` did the job, thank you! Wasn't aware of other declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use !important after margin:0 auto.
Eg- margin:0 auto !important.
!important properties can not be overridden by any other classes or IDs